# How to set the first row of CSV data as column name in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulk-insert

I am using BULK INSERT to read a csv file in SQL Server. Is there a way to keep the first row as column name while I am reading the file?

If not, after reading the data from the csv (from second row), how can I add column names to it?

Any help/comments/suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If not, after reading the data from the csv (from second row), how can
>   I add column names to it?

I would put your focus here. First, create your table with yoru column names, data types, etc.

```
create table myTable (column1 <datatype>, column2 <datatype>)
```

Then, bulk insert into it but ignore the first row.

```
bulk insert myTable
   from 'C:\somefile.csv',
   with( firstrow = 2,
         fieldterminator = ',',
         rowterminator = '\n')
```

If it's dynamic, then you may want to look into [`openrowset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ms190312(v=sql.100)).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are importing a standard CSV, you can dynamically create the table as such:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @filePath NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'C:/SomeFolder/yourImportFile.csv'
DECLARE @tableName NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'yourTableName'
DECLARE @colString NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = 'SELECT @res = LEFT(BulkColumn, CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),BulkColumn)) FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @filePath + ''', SINGLE_CLOB) AS x'
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@res NVARCHAR(MAX) output', @colString output;

SELECT @sql = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' + @tableName + ';  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[' + @tableName + ']( ' + STRING_AGG(name, ', ') + ' ) '
FROM (
    SELECT ' [' + value + '] nvarchar(max) ' as name
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@colString, ',')
) t

EXECUTE(@sql)
```

and then bulk insert the data as @scsimon suggested:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.yourTableName.
FROM 'C:/SomeFolder/yourImportFile.csv'
WITH ( 
    FORMAT='CSV', 
    FIRSTROW = 2, 
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', 
    FIELDQUOTE= '"',
    TABLOCK  
)
```